# Does xml tag allow multiple attributes?

Tags: xml, pycharm

For example:

```
<Rule name="test_1", type="gameName">
    <note>
        ...
    </note>
    <tests>
        ...
    </tests>
</Rule>
```

After I added 'type' attribute to the tag `<Rule></Rule>`, PyCharm says that the xml block is invalid by showing 'unexpected tokens' with a red flag. Does xml tag allow multiple attributes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, XML can contain multiple attributes. But you don't have to seperate the attribute with a comma, instead you have to use a space. This would be the correct way to write your example.

`<Rule name="test_1" type="gameName">`